# Go: sql RowsAffected with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, go

I struggle to find some proper documentation which describes the semantic of the RowsAffected value other than that:

> RowsAffected returns the number of rows affected by an update, insert, or delete. Not every database or database driver may support this.

I'm using a query with  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE and the value of RowsAffected is 2 after an update. Is it because it reduces to execution to delete and insert?

The server is an MySql server Ver 8.0.12 for osx10.13 on x86_64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_affected_rows()` is the equivalent of the SQL function [ROW_COUNT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count).

For `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` the documentation states:

> For `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statements, the affected-rows
>   value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an
>   existing row is updated, and 0 if an existing row is set to its
>   current values. If you specify the `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` flag, the
>   affected-rows value is 1 (not 0) if an existing row is set to its
>   current values.

Comment: great thanks, did was not sure is one to one, so didn't check mysql docu. Thanks!